# Как изменить цвет меню приложений Windows 10

Tags: windows, menu, themes

Дело в том, что многие программы я использую с темной темой, но вот само верхнее меню приложений остается белым(как вы можете видеть на скриншоте ниже), что очень сильно мешает.

Есть ли какой-то способ это исправить?

[image: меню приложений]

Comment: У вас Windows 10 или просто похоже?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/222614/how-to-enable-windows-10s-hidden-dark-theme/

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 1):

В Windows есть встроенная темная тема для настольных приложений, но, вероятно, она не идеальна. Чтобы включить его, зайдите в `Settings > Ease of Access > High Contrast`. Справа включите опцию `Turn on High Contras` и установите в раскрывающемся списке `Choose a Theme` значение `High Contrast Black`. Нажмите `Apply`, чтобы сохранить настройки.

---

[source](https://www.howtogeek.com/222614/how-to-enable-windows-10s-hidden-dark-theme/)

Comment: Да, я пытался сделать все именно так, но смог активировать контрастность только из меню входа в систему, но та контрастность не настраивается, а контрастность в самой системе делает белыми половину приложений

Comment: @dodickgod  `но, вероятно, она не идеальна` ...